# JAVA FX Modify TableView Column

Tags: java, javafx-2

So I have a TableView setup in my app that lists the current system users for the app itself. The TableView has 4 columns, UserId, UserName, CreatedDate, and Active

The getActive() method returns an integer of 1 or 0 respectively if the user is active or inactive.

My table column currently outputs the values of 1 or 0 for each user. I would like to however format that column as showing Yes or No instead of 1 or 0.

Is it possible to bind the returned value of the column to a String like that?

Here is what I am using to set the column data in my initialize method:

```
activeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find a way to do what I needed to. Not entirely sure this is the best method so I am open to additional suggestions.

```
activeCol.setCellValueFactory((CellDataFeatures<User, String> u) -> {
    String userActive = String.valueOf(u.getValue().getActive());
    userActive= (!userActive.equals("0")) ? "Yes" : "No";
    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(userActive);
});
```